# Function chaining in php

Tags: php, laravel

Am trying to create a function which will be used in various part of my application. But i need to chain some of the methods like the way laravel chains its global response function like the following

```
response()->json(['data'=>'stuck with chaining functions']);
```

i need to implement something like this

```
db_logger()->create("user","Raise work order");
db_logger()->deleted("user","Updated wored order with id 1");
```

but am stuck. This is what i have tried so far but to know success

```
use App\Models\LogSheet;

if(!function_exists('db_logger')){

 function db_logger(){

    function created($user, $activity){
        saveLog($user, $activity, "created");
    };

    $updated = function ($user, $activity){
        saveLog($user, $activity, "updated");
    };

    $deleted = function ($user, $activity){
        saveLog($user, $activity, "deleted");
    };

    $read = function ($user, $activity){
        saveLog($user, $activity, "");
    };

    $log = function ($user, $activity){
        saveLog($user, $activity, "");
    };

    $saveLog = function ($user, $activity,$activity_type){
        return LogSheet::create(compact('user','activity','activity_type'));
    };

  }
}
```

But to no avail.

**NB:** Please i know about class method Chaining. I want the laravel style of function chaining.

Comment: The laravel function is probably just returning an instance of an object and then you call a method with `->`. `->` is only used to access properties or methods from a class. (btw: those semicolons at the end of the function definitions are useless.)

Comment: please can you give am example please. I have gone through the laravel helper files but can't find my way through

Comment: Laravel doesn't chain functions, it chains object methods.... using a `with` "function" or a façade that returns a specified object instance

Comment: @oseintow Here: https://eval.in/531459 ;)

Comment: As the guys said, Laravel doesn't chain functions, but object methods, as you can see the helper method that you are using as example is resolving out of the IoC container the response class                 `function response($content = '', $status = 200, array $headers = [])
    {
        $factory = app(ResponseFactory::class);

        if (func_num_args() === 0) {
            return $factory;
        }

        return $factory->make($content, $status, $headers);
    }`   only for that reason you can chain the available method in this class

Comment: thanks Rizier. Will try it out and see how it goes

Comment: Thanks Jarguez01 thats very informative